# Show warning on form submit if no checkbox is check JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have placed an onsubmit function onto a form which checks to see if certain checkboxes are checked.

The problem I am having is that I only require one checkbox from each column to be checked, there are 3 columns in total with around 6 different checkboxes in each column - every checkbox in a column shares the same ID (this is what makes it hard for me).

The below script works, but it requires all of the boxes in each column to be checked, how can I modify it to still submit only if one checkbox in each column is checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('uwpqsffrom_731');
    form.onsubmit = function() {
        var no1 = 0, no2 = 0, no3 = 0;
    var list;
    list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[0][term][]');
    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
       if (list[i].checked)
       {
           no1++;
       }
    }
    list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[1][term][]');
    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
       if (list[i].checked)
       {
           no2++;
       }
    }
    list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[2][call]');
    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
       if (list[i].checked)
       {
           no3++;
       }
    }
    list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[2][term][]');
    for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
    {
       if (list[i].checked)
       {
           no3++;
       }
    }
    if ( no1 == 0 || no2 == 0 || no3 == 0 )
    {
        alert("Please select at least one option from each section");
        return false;
    }
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

You can see that there are everal checkboxes with the same ID - I only require 1 of them to be checked for the form to submit.

```
<form id="uwpqsffrom_731" method="get" action="http://test.com/">

<div class="uform_title">Find Your Perfect Venue</div><input type="hidden" name="unonce" value="a92b348757"><input type="hidden" name="uformid" value="731"><input type="hidden" name="s" value="uwpsfsearchtrg">

<div class="uwpqsf_class  tax-check-0 togglecheck">
<span class="taxolabel-0">Guests</span>
<input type="hidden" name="taxo[0][name]" value="number-of-guests">
<input type="hidden" name="taxo[0][opt]" value="1">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="150-180">150-180</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="180-200">180-200</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="20-50">20-50</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="200-350">200-350</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="200-380">200-380</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="350-500">350-500</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="50-65">50-65</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="500-1000">500-1000</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-0" name="taxo[0][term][]" value="65-150">65-150</label>
</div>

<div class="uwpqsf_class  tax-check-1 togglecheck">
<span class="taxolabel-1">Event Type</span>
<input type="hidden" name="taxo[1][name]" value="event-type">
<input type="hidden" name="taxo[1][opt]" value="1">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="awards-dinner">Awards Dinner</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="awards-dinner-dance">Awards Dinner Dance</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="barbat-mitzvah">Bar/Bat Mitzvah</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="cocktail-party">Cocktail Party</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="dinner">Dinner</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="dinner-dance">Dinner Dance</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="networking-event">Networking Event</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="party">Party</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-1" name="taxo[1][term][]" value="vip-experience">VIP Experience</label>
</div>

<div class="uwpqsf_class  tax-check-2 togglecheck">
<span class="taxolabel-2">Venue Preference</span>
<input type="hidden" name="taxo[2][name]" value="venue-locations">
<input type="hidden" name="taxo[2][opt]" value="">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-2" name="taxo[2][call]" class="chktaxoall">All Venues</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-2" name="taxo[2][term][]" value="london-dungeon">London</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-2" name="taxo[2][term][]" value="madame-tussauds">New York</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-2" name="taxo[2][term][]" value="sea-life">Russia</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" id="tchkb-2" name="taxo[2][term][]" value="stardome-4d">Spain</label>
</div>

<div class="uwpqsf_class  uwpqsf_submit">
<input type="submit" id="uwpqsf_id_btn" value="Search" alt="[Submit]" class="usfbtn ">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: it would really be helpful if you could add the HTML as well

Comment: Ok I added some exmple HTML,it's a massive form so I couldn't paste it all!

Comment: Why you assign same id?

Comment: I don't see how they are separated into columns so I'm just going to guess. First of all, you can't use the same id for more than 1 checkbox. If you want to select multiple items by the same selector, use the class for that. Also, if you don't have the 3 columns separated from each other (either in distinct container or with classes or attributes) you need to go check each one individually. So I suggest if this is your actual HTML to change it.

Comment: Each column is contained within a separate container (div) the HTML code is just an example of the check boxes - I understand he issue regarding using the same ID on multiple checkboxes but I'm afraid this is out of my hands as it is a plugin generating the form.

Comment: Yeah, but we would need to see an example of the actual code, not something else (most of us know how a checkbox should look)

Comment: @CatalinDeaconescu OK I have just added the full HTML code

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick note: they still have the same Id but I'll work around that :)

Comment: Thank you :) Unfortunately there is nothing I can do regarding the same ID's since it's generated via a plugin - annoying I know!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54211/discussion-between-catalin-deaconescu-and-ruffcut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made some changes to your original `javascript`, but you should be able to just copy - paste my code over yours easily.

```
function test() {
var no1 = 0, no2 = 0, no3 = 0;
var list;
list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[0][term][]');
for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   if (list[i].checked)
   {
       no1++;
   }
}
list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[1][term][]');
for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   if (list[i].checked)
   {
       no2++;
   }
}
list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[2][call]');
for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   if (list[i].checked)
   {
       no3++;
   }
}
list = document.getElementsByName('taxo[2][term][]');
for(i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
   if (list[i].checked)
   {
       no3++;
   }
}

if ( no1 == 0 || no2 == 0 || no3 == 0 )
{
    alert("Please select at least one option from each section");
    return false;
}
```

}

Sorry it's a little sloppy, I don't really handle `javascript` well without `jQuery`, and there were some limitations due to your markup (didn't change that at all as you said it was all generated by a pluging.

Anyway, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWT65/2/) of it as well

(note: had to do the `for` twice for the last column as the names we're different ...)

(note2: if you can also use `jQuery`, I can clean it up really nicely)

If you require only one of the `checkboxes` from each column to be selected I would recomend using `radio-buttons`. If you can't, just change it to `if ( no1 !=1 && no2 != 1 && no3 != 1 )`

Comment: You my friend are awesome - it works perfectly in the jsfiddle, however when I place it on the site nothing happens, also nothing in the console related to it :(

Comment: Did you add my code in the bind function you had, or did you keep it as a new function with onsubmit calling it ?

Comment: I think I know why, kind of stupid of me really - I need to place the onSubmit function to the form. Should I just take the first part from my script and tag it on the front?

Comment: Should work in both cases yes. Either add the function to the form as onsubmit, or just paste my code (without the function) to the beginning of your code

Comment: Ok I have updated my question with theJavaScript code with the code you provided + wrapped it in my 'bind function' it's not working - does it look ok?

Comment: worked for me ... tried it in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KWT65/3  If you want we can troubleshoot in the chat I opened ...

Comment: Awesome, I copied it form the fiddle and it worked - you're a legend, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> how can I modify it to still submit only if one checkbox in each column is checked.

You should make all your `checkbox` to have common name. Then iterate the `checkbox` with name, use `document.getElementsByName('name')`

Your `html` should look something like this:

150-180
180-200

```
var chkBox = document.getElementsByName('taxo');

for (var i = 0; i < chkBox.length; i++){
     if (chkBox.checked == true){

         submitForm();

         break;
     }
}

function submitForm(){
    //submit form
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is I need one box checked from each column (3 in total) - wouldn't this still send the form if one box is checked in total?